# Make a view whose contents appear across all storyboard scenes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

My app is made of 2 storyboard cenes, but these have a mutual `UILabel` whose value shouldn't change with the change of the scene, (as it does now) so I was thinking of moving this label to a view that would be on both controllers, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply have an outer ViewController with the label in it's view.  Two more view controllers have the scenes, and their views are subviews of the outer view controller.

Perhaps the inner view controllers use a navigation controller, or whatever is appropriate for your needs.